# persistent rzc discover exited with code -2147450730

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I understand this is usually a pointer error. However, I can't seem to solve it here is what I have tried:

- Repair visual studio
- Repair .NET core
- Reinstall visual studio
- Reinstall .NET core
- Clean and rebuild the solution

After doing all of these I am still getting the same error. Does anyone have any more ideas on how I could solve this issue? In case it is needed it is being triggered on line 79 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets which is the following code block

```
  <RazorTagHelper
  Debug="$(_RazorDebugTagHelperTask)"
  DebugTool="$(_RazorDebugTagHelperTool)"
  ToolAssembly="$(_RazorToolAssembly)"
  UseServer="$(UseRazorBuildServer)"
  ForceServer="$(_RazorForceBuildServer)"
  PipeName="$(_RazorBuildServerPipeName)"
  Version="$(RazorLangVersion)"
  Configuration="@(ResolvedRazorConfiguration)"
  Extensions="@(ResolvedRazorExtension)"
  Assemblies="@(RazorReferencePath)"
  ProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
  TagHelperManifest="$(_RazorTagHelperOutputCache)">
  <Output
    TaskParameter="TagHelperManifest"
    ItemName="FileWrites"/>
</RazorTagHelper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by having to install an older depreciated version of .NET alongside the version of .NET being used for the project with the older version that was required to be installed being version [2.0.9](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.0/runtime?utm_source=getdotnetcore&utm_medium=referral)

Answer (score 1):

In my case i solved installing dotnet-hosting-6.0.5-win.exe

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#common-errors